# Can we recover the bases of two infinite-dimensional vector spaces into a tensor product?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

I know that in general, if V,W are infinite-dimensional vector spaces with basis {${v_i}$} and {${w_j}$} respectively it holds that V⊗W has as basis {${v_i⊗w_j}$}.

My question is: what about the reciprocal? That is: if {${v_i}$} and {${w_j}$} are families of vectors in V and W respectively such that the family {${v_i⊗w_j}$} is a basis of V⊗W, are {${v_i}$} and {${w_j}$} bases of V and W respectively?

Comment: Can you state precisely what your question is?  It's not clear exactly what statement you want to be true.

Comment: What is your desired statement exactly? If $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are families of vectors in $V$ and $W$ respectively such that the family $\{v_i\otimes v_j\}$ is a basis of $V\otimes W$, then $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are bases of $V$ and $W$, respectively?

Comment: Thank you for posing the question as that in the comment, @HagenvonEitzen. It was clearer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes: if $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$ then $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are bases of $V$ and $W$, respectively. Actually, we need to account for the following slight technicality: we must assume that $V, W \neq 0$.

*Proof.* Since $V, W \neq 0$, $\{w_j\} \neq \varnothing$; fix some vector $w$ from the indexed set $\{w_j\}$. Let $g : V \otimes W \to V$ be the linear function defined by $v_i \otimes w_j \mapsto v_i$. Let $f : V \to V \otimes W$ be the linear function $f(v) = v \otimes w$. By inspection, $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_{V}$, so $g$ is surjective, which means that $\{v_i\}$ spans $V$. To show that $\{v_i\}$ is linearly independent, suppose $\alpha_1 v_{i_1} + \dots + \alpha_k v_{i_k} = 0$ for some scalars $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_k$ and some indices $i_1, \dots, i_k$. Then
$$0 = f(\alpha_1 v_{i_1} + \dots + \alpha_k v_{i_k}) = \alpha_1 (v_{i_1} \otimes w) + \dots + \alpha_k (v_{i_k} \otimes w).$$
Since $\{v_i \otimes w_j\}$ is linearly independent, we conclude that $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_k = 0$, as desired. This shows that $\{v_i\}$ is a basis of $V$; symmetrically we have that $\{w_j\}$ is a basis of $W$.

Edit: posted a little too soon, the proof is complete now!

Comment: Thank you. Can we find in here a (hidden) application of the universal mapping property of the tensor? On the other hand, the homomorphism g does not work as a projection (which is not allowed for the tensor product). Am I right?

Comment: That's right, the map $g$ should not be thought of as a projection, because in general an element of $V \otimes W$ will be a linear combination of many different basis vectors $v_i \otimes w_j$. Indeed, I'm pretty sure the map $g$ depends on the families  $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$, and not just the vector spaces $V$ and $W$. To be honest, I'm not sure if/where the universal property appears here. I've really only used the *construction* of the tensor product, which is in some sense equivalent, but only once you've proven that the construction satisfies the universal property.

Comment: @gibarian Was this a sufficient answer? I can expand it if you need more detail.